# Web requests in docker-compose on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, httprequest

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904060/how-to-push-docker-containers-managed-by-docker-compose-to-heroku) and the comments in [this post](https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/how-to-run-dockerized-apps-on-heroku-and-its-pretty-great-76e07e610e22) discuss how to deploy projects managed using docker-compose to Heroku. However I get the impression that the result will be similar to deploying each docker image separately.

Does this mean that web requests between the docker containers will be sent as actual requests and thus slower than normal requests on the docker-compose network?