# How to deploy application with docker-compose.yaml file in Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

How to deploy docker-compose.yaml file in Heroku for a certain application which contains dependencies on other images. i.e. using a single docker-compose.yml will I be able to deploy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904060/how-to-push-docker-containers-managed-by-docker-compose-to-heroku this might help

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't support docker-compose.yml files the only work around i found is to use [heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml).