# Heroku hosting database

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For those of you who use Heroku for hosting, what database do you use? For example, `PostgreSql`, `MongoDB` or something else.
I wrote a bot on `sqlite3`, but then I found out that Heroku doesn't support it, and doesn't overwrite files at all

Comment: I use node + mongoDB atlas with mongoose and it works fine

Comment: Go with mongodb atlas

Comment: Heroku has postgress https://www.heroku.com/postgres.

you can use sqlite in Heroku, in fact you can deploy any tech stack to Heroku, consider using docker(docker compose kind of strategy) check this answer out. but keep in mind that data is not persisted.. just for experiments u can use this strategy. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904060/how-to-push-docker-containers-managed-by-docker-compose-to-heroku

Comment: Since you already have a bot that talks SQL, it'd be easiest to switch to another SQL solution such as PostgreSQL (which, I believe, has a free tier on Heroku). MongoDB would be a very different beast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the cloud-based solutions for databases like Atlas (My personal choice),
Here you can find what Heroku recommends:
https://www.heroku.com/managed-data-services

Here Other AWS solutions [Amazon Relational Database Service](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/?trk=ps_a131L0000058UA5QAM&trkCampaign=pac_paidsearch_q4109_RDS_PDP_adgroups&sc_channel=ps&sc_campaign=pac_1019_paidsearch_US_OpenSource_nonbrand_prosp_database&sc_outcome=PaaS_Digital_Marketing&sc_geo=NAMER&sc_country=US&sc_publisher=Google&sc_content=database&sc_medium=PAC-PaaS-P%7CPS-GO%7CNon-Brand%7CDesktop%7CPA%7CDatabase%7CRDS%7CUS%7CEN%7CText&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!433618291197!b!!g!!%2Bdatabases&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwp4j6BRCRARIsAGq4yMEU7_ieyh-EawdD-NQyiwa-JeSbW-jJUkao0AHclYVdKEb703q6UCwaArVFEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!433618291197!b!!g!!%2Bdatabases) this AWS RDS solutions are present in Heroku [Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/other-data-stores)

Comment: Based on my own experiences, using cloud storage APIs (such as jsonstore), it leads to elevated levels in latency. This is considerably more noticeable in context of a Discord bot...