# Is possible deploy in heroku a (Django, Flask, FastApi) Rest API that use celery with redis using Docker?

Tags: docker, api, heroku, docker-compose, celery

I'm working in a api rest in python with celery and worker redis. In my local pc I need to run two servers, the flask/fastapi server and the celery server. My question is if is possible deploy the app in heroku, and how is the configuration of the Dockerfiles and the docker-compose.yml. This is the project structure:

[image]

Project: https://github.com/SebastianJHM/fastapi_celery_redis

UPDATE:
I create a heroku.yml and I try to deploy.

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-redis
      as: REDIS
build:
  docker:
    web: app/Dockerfile
    worker: worker_tasks/Dockerfile
```

The deploy was good but I have this error with the connection of redis:
[image]

Comment: Hard to answer that question since you provided very little details. Please specify the setup you already have!

Answer (score 2):

Of corse it is possible to run this setup locally and on Heroku. If I understood you correctly you want to run celery as the worker in a container and Redis as the message broker and result backend. Since you did not provide anything about the setup you already have I can show you a standard setup to get going locally. Add these 2 services to your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  worker:
    build: ./worker_tasks
    command: celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
    depends_on:
      - redis
 redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

To run everything on Heroku, the Heroic dev center has an [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku) that explains it better and more detailed than I ever could.

To deploy the project on Heroku you could create a `heroku.yml` which is very similar to a `docker-compose.yml` file; see
[How to push Docker containers managed by Docker-compose to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904060/how-to-push-docker-containers-managed-by-docker-compose-to-heroku)

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin!!! I'm new in this. I currently have two Dockerfiles, one in the application folder and one in workers. I have been able to deploy docker images after building them. But it is not clear to me if in this case I should use a heroku.yml or if docker-compose is enough.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I changed the docker compose to fit to your project structur. Should work locally now. I think you should use a heroku.yml, I provided a link to a former Post above. If that helps please consider accepting my answer :)